# In PEP 3141, why doesn't Number have an add method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

PEP [3141](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/) defines a numerical hierarchy with `Complex.__add__` but no `Number.__add__`. This seems to be a weird choice, since the other numeric type `Decimal` that (virtually) derives from `Number` also implements an add method.

So why is it this way? If I want to add type annotations or assertions to my code, should I use `x:(Complex, Decimal)`? Or `x:Number` and ignore the fact that this declaration is practically meaningless?

Comment: From PEP 3141: "This class only helps with overloading; it doesn't provide any operations." (so also: no subtraction, multiplication, etc).

Comment: @SimeonVisser you're begging the question. If the PEP says that for a reason, what is that reason? Why does `Complex` define these operators if they aren't worth defining on `Number`?

Comment: What if I want to define a numeric type that doesn't support addition? Number exists as base class in the hierarchy but why should it enforce that certain operations must be supported?

Comment: You would run into the same issue as if you wanted a `Complex` type that doesn't support division.As far as I can see, the only *reason* to have a `Number` class is to check that operators have numerical semantics (duck typing on operators is wrong, as it would lead me to believe `list` is a number since it supports `__add__` and `__mul__`).

Comment: @rotu - I think you're willfully ignoring the reason given in the PEP. Just back up one sentence from what Simeon mentioned: *We begin with a Number class to make it easy for people to be fuzzy about what kind of number they expect.* The whole point of `Number` is so that it can be the Pythonic answer to the practical part of your question (regarding annotations and assertions). Essentially, it is establishing the convention (a kind of social contract if you will) that numeric types will satisfy `isinstance(x, Number)`. Obviously this convention is not enforceable, but it's useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer can be found in the [Rejected Alternatives](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/#rejected-alternatives):

> The initial version of this PEP defined an algebraic hierarchy
>   inspired by a Haskell Numeric Prelude [3] including `MonoidUnderPlus`,
>   `AdditiveGroup`, `Ring`, and `Field`, and mentioned several other possible
>   algebraic types before getting to the numbers. We had expected this to
>   be useful to people using vectors and matrices, **but the NumPy
>   community really wasn't interested** ...

There are more complicated number systems where addition is clearly not supported. They could have went in much more detail with their class hierarchy (and originally intended to), but there is a lack of interest in the community. Hence, it is easier just to leave `Numbers` unspecified for anyone who wants to get more complicated.

Note that `Monoids` are an example where only one binary operation is defined.

Answer (score 2):

In numbers.py. There is note on Decimal and Real.

```
 24 ## Notes on Decimal
 25 ## ----------------
 26 ## Decimal has all of the methods specified by the Real abc, but it should
 27 ## not be registered as a Real because decimals do not interoperate with
 28 ## binary floats (i.e.  Decimal('3.14') + 2.71828 is undefined).  But,
 29 ## abstract reals are expected to interoperate (i.e. R1 + R2 should be
 30 ## expected to work if R1 and R2 are both Reals).
```

And also put some related links here. Really a good question, drive me dig the hole around. :P

- [A related github issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/75)
- [PEP 3119](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/#id13) Which all about
  ABC(Abstract Base Class) and PEP3141 defines Number part.
- [cpython/Lib/numbers.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/numbers.py)